# php IF условие не хочет работать

Tags: php

Не могу понять в чем проблема... Есть условие if, которое в случае определенного значения показывает нужный div, а если значение не подходит, то ничего не делает. У меня же получается так, что значение не подходит, но панель все равно показывается...

```
<?php if ($results['u_role'] = 1) { ?>
    <div class="adminpanel"><img class='adminimg' src="<?= $resultsrole['user_role_img']; ?>"><a href="admin.php"><?= $resultsrole['role_name']; ?></a></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

$results['u_role'] = 2, проверял через echo. Но div все равно показывается =(

Comment: `if ($results['u_role'] == 1) ` исправьте.

Comment: ну как всегда смотрю везде, где не нужно))) спасибо

Comment: если вы часто совершаете подобные ошибки, то попробуйте взять за правило писать первым операндом константное значение, а вторым - переменную: `if (1 == $results['u_role'])`, и тогда при такой записи `if (1 = $results['u_role'])` вам будет брошена ошибка самим интерпретатором.

Comment: На самом деле изначально было условие <=, я проверял как они выполняются для всех пользователей, и у меня ничего не менялось, я только сейчас заметил, что роль пользователя не менялась при смене в бд, а менялась только при перезаходе. Поэтому я целый час убил ищач проблему там, где ее не было, а потом еще и сломал то, что работало =D

Comment: А ещё лучше тождественное сравнение '===', за одно проверяет тип данных.